# Find Most common elements in list of list

Tags: python, list, group-by

I have a bunch of keys and values

```
Key 1  ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'chicken']
key 1  ['cake', 'orange', 'apple']
key 2  ['oreo','chips']
```

Now I wanna group by keys and only have the values which are present in 50% of the keys so the output would be

```
key 1  ['orange', 'apple']
Key 2  ['oreo','chips']
```

I'm confused about the Data Structure I should use to store this. Should I just use list of list to store values then search through all values each time and get the top. Is there an more optimized way

Comment: Your keys are inconsistent: `Key 1` and `key 1` vs `key 1`; `key 2` vs `Key 2`. So it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Maybe you want a list of tuples: `[(1, ['apple', ...]), (1, ['cake', ...]), (2, ['oreo', ...])]`

Comment: Or a dict with lists of lists? `{1: [['apple', ...], ['cake', ...]], 2: [['oreo', ...]]}`

Comment: To clarify my first comment: you can't have duplicate keys. I thought you had the word "key" as part of the key but apparently not after reading again.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply have a list of pairs with the key and the list. It could work something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from collections import Counter

def frequency_filter(group, freq):
    group = list(group)
    c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(items) for _, items in group))
    n = round(len(group) * freq)
    return [k for k, v in c.items() if v > n]

data = [('key 1', ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'chicken']),
        ('key 1', ['cake', 'orange', 'apple']),
        ('key 2', ['oreo','chips'])]
result = {k: frequency_filter(g, 0.5) for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda t: t[0])}
print(result)
# {'key 1': ['orange', 'apple'], 'key 2': ['oreo', 'chips']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write some function / code to group them by keys (maybe you've already done this).

As you group them add the values to each respective key that match. So key1 and key1 will all go into the dictionary in the key of key1.

After they are grouped go through each key in the dictionary and remove any elements that are not there 50% of the time and then remove the duplicates of the others so it just has the items that are there 50% of the time.

If you want to use two dictionaries, you can pull out the values that are in each key 50% or more of the time and store them in the same manor as you did above but a separate dictionary.

Here's some documentation for dictionaries you can add, remove, and update easily:
[W3Schools Python Dictionary Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is storing the values as dict, with:

```
lst = [
{'key': 'key 1', 'values': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'chicken']},
{'key': 'key 1', 'values': ['cake', 'orange', 'apple']},
{'key': 'key 2', 'values': ['oreo','chips']},
]

from itertools import groupby

out = []
for v, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda k: k['key']), lambda k: k['key']):
    l = list(g)
    s = set(v for i in l for v in i['values'])
    c = [(v, sum(v in i['values'] for i in l) / len(l)) for v in s]
    out.append({v: [v for v, cnt in c if cnt > 0.5]})

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=40)
```

Prints:

```
[{'key 1': ['apple', 'orange']},
 {'key 2': ['oreo', 'chips']}]
```